# Tree edit distance, python code for Tree bracket format, Converting 2 dimensional tree to one string

Tags: python

Can someone help me with the code to breakdown a decision tree into a  1 dimensional tree bracket format in python. The algorithm to do so is

INPUT: x—decision tree

OUTPUT: TBF is the tree x in the tree bracket format

Function UpdateNodes(x):

if NumberOfChildrenOfNM (x) is not null then

NM (x) is the list of node attribute names of x

Set TBF = TBF + ’{ ’+ NM (x)

for j = 1 to NumberOfChildrenOfNM (x) do

Call UpdateNodes(x)

Set TBF = TBF+ ’}’

end for

end if

But when I am trying to implement this I am getting error